# 7 - Display translated content using Flexslider Views Slideshow

Tags: views, i18n-l10n, javascript

I have a Views block which uses [FlexSlider Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider_views_slideshow) as the format. The fields which supply the captions have translations but only the default (English) versions are displayed with the FlexSlider Views Slideshow format. [Example of the Views block using FlexSlider Views Slideshow](http://eiado.prevision.com.au/) can be seen here.

I have a Views page as part of the same view which uses unformatted list as the format. This handles the translated as expected. [Example of the Views page](http://eiado.prevision.com.au/about/photos) is here.

The captions are from the title field of the content type which use the Titles module so they can be translated.

Other modules in the mix are i18n, i18n_block, i18n_field, i18n_views which enable the content to be translated in the first place.

**So, my question is**: How to get the FlexSlider Views Slideshow to display translated content?

I've checked the *Field Language* setting is Current User's Language in the View.

I've checked the *Make this block translatable* option is checked in the block's configuration.

I've checked the *Language Detection Settings* are ordered; *URL, User, Default*

I've cleared all the caches.

I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be because of the "language detection" configuration.

So check this configuration via *Configuration -> Languages -> detection and selection*: the order should be 'URL, Default, User', and not something like 'Default, URL, User'.

Comment: Reviewed my *Detection and Selection* settings which were ordered; URL, User, Default. Reordering to; URL, Default, User did not change the Views block's output. I appreciate the suggestion.